# How to allow only my app to access firebase without a login?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am storing my app's data on Firebase and this being my first project on Firebase is proving to be much more difficult than I thought. I have gone through the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users) and it says that we can login a user with their email and password or use other login options like Google or Facebook etc. However I don't want user's to login to my application but only read and write data to firebase **if they are using my app**. Right now I am using public rules for my firebase but then anyone with a reference to my firebase URL can read and write to the database. How do I overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about using anonymous authentication? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth

Comment: You have already introduced a major threat by making rules Public. Best way to overcome this is to implement Authentication. Period.

Comment: @finki what is difference between anonymous authentication and public.

Answer (score 13):

Enable Anonymous sing-in provider under Sing-in Method under Authentication tab in your Firebase Console and 
use [firebase anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth)

Comment: i am facing an issue using firebase anonymous authentication. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays you can accomplish this by enabling [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check), which only allows requests coming from your real app on a genuine device to make requests these protected services on your Firebase project:

- Realtime Database
- Cloud Firestore
- Cloud Storage
- Cloud Functions (callable functions)

You can also implement App Check in your own backend code to provide it with the same protection.

As the documentation says:

> Using App Check does not guarantee the elimination of all abuse, but by integrating with App Check, you are taking an important step towards abuse protection for your backend resources.

For the above services, that'd typically mean that you'll also want to implement Firebase Authentication and then implement fine-grained access control in server-side [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules).

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Real-Time DB **does not allow access to Un-Authorized Users**.

Making the Firebase Database Rules true for Read & Write is not the way as  (Chintan Soni) said.

So a Authentication mechanism is the best way!

Comment: Does firebase alows an app to publish with read ,write access without login(authentication)

Comment: you can use anonymous login

Comment: A firebase database can be public. All depends of auth rules.

Comment: I implemented auth into my android app also i have set rules in firebase to protect my firebase project from other app users. But still its not working.

Answer (score -6):

If you only want to use firebase database you should:

1. Download SDK from gradle https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
2. In firebase console create project and add your app, download json i put it on your Android Studio Project
3. Add database dependiences 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
4. Configure rules in console. You could also disable rules (recomended only for first tests:
   "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": true
   }

I also recomended update Android Studio to version 2.1 or 2.2 with Firebase integration included.

Comment: even if user doesn't have any application key?

Answer (score -9):

Set Database rules up as follows:

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: This approach is for testing purposes only. It's a big security violation if used in production; anyone can read/write your database.

Comment: This should not be used in production.