# Add some kind of auth to Firebase realtime database without using Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Firebase have rules for `read` and `write` but how can I create a rule that allows me to `read`/`write` just from my app (like an `api-key` or something).

I dont want to use Firebase Auth just to make my database not public.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395025/how-to-allow-only-my-app-to-access-firebase-without-a-login/38395361#38395361

Comment: Essentially the URL of you Firebase database can be seen as an API key already.  But having an API key that you distribute to your users would not prevent abuse. To securely access the data, you will need to use authentication on top of that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005984/how-to-prevent-other-access-to-my-firebase