# Locking down Firebase DB access to specific apps

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I think from searching the web this is not technically possible but I want to ask again in case I'm missing something.

I have an app that uses Firebase. Reading and writing is locked down through security rules for authorised users only but there's certain information I want unauthorised users to be able to access (so I don't have to put a login wall in front of them, influencing churn).

What I want to know is, is there any way of locking down this read access that only *my* app can call the DB? I know I can lock down domains to prevent someone writing localhost scrapers but what's to stop someone cloning and re-skinning an app and pointing it to the same back end? Is it possible to achieve this using your certificates fingerprint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to limit access to your database to just your app. That just doesn't match with the cloud-based nature of the Firebase APIs. Anyone that knows the URL of your database can in in principle access it, and security rule are **the** way to ensure all access is authorized.

Note that security rules are not an all-or-nothing approach: you can require sign-in for some parts of your database, while leaving other parts publicly readable. But you *can't* make the publicly readable parts only be readable by your own app.

Some previous questions on the same topic:

- [how to make sure only my own website (clientside code) can talk to Firebase backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890330/how-to-make-sure-only-my-own-website-clientside-code-can-talk-to-firebase-back) (pretty much my go-to answer for this)
- [How to allow only my app to access firebase without a login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395025/how-to-allow-only-my-app-to-access-firebase-without-a-login)
- [Restrict Firebase database access to one Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818782/restrict-firebase-database-access-to-one-android-app)
- [How to allow only my app to access firebase without a login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395025/how-to-allow-only-my-app-to-access-firebase-without-a-login/49284538)

**Update**: since May 2021 you **can** actually restrict access to just users of *your* App by implementing [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and especially the first link, I think it makes more sense now

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that maybe helps you or anyone that have a similar question. I answered it in this question:

[Restricting Cloud Firestore to a specific domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425585/restricting-cloud-firestore-to-a-specific-domain/66020616#66020616)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two ways to do this:

The first less secure method be to use request.referrer in your security rules.  Here, we limit it to a domain for write access:

```
   ".write": "request.referrer != null && request.referrer.startsWith('https://your-web-app-domain.com')"
```

Second, and much more securely, firebase has added [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check)  to offer and extra layer of security prior to ever seeing the security rules file.