# Restricting Cloud Firestore to a specific domain

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is there a way to restrict Cloud Firestore (for hosting/web) to do CRUD operations with restrictions to one domain only, say `xyz.com`?

For example, the rule below locks `read, update, delete` without authorisation but you can still `write` things to the database.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /coming-soon-email-ids/{document=**} {
      allow write;
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == !null;
    }
  }
}
```

Or do I have to integrate Google's firewall in it?

Comment: check this out https://blog.jimmycai.com/p/firebase-limit-access-to-certain-domains/. Not quite a domain restriction but for google's login you could restrict to a certain domain for G suit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firebase security rules aren't able to restrict access to a web domain.  In a very general sense, it is not possible, because Firestore is intended to be accessed from mobile clients around the world, using web, Android, and iOS.  Android and iOS clients never appear to be coming from some domain.  They just directly access the database via the provided client library, or sometimes through the Firestore REST API.  Web clients may even spoof their apparent domain (which is only really available by the insecure "Referrer" header in an HTTP request).

You can only really restrict access to users signed in to your app or site using Firebase Authentication, but you can't limit *where* they come from.

Comment: Ok is there a way to restric to one or more fields?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. It sounds like the beginning of a whole new question that's unrelated to this one.

Comment: If logged in via google (G suit for instance) I think we simply check for the email domain in the firestore rules

Comment: Can't use the apiKey to build my own app that points to your firestore and then implement anonymous sign-on too though?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question, and I coming up with a solution. You can do sign In anonymously:

```
const signIn = async () => {
auth.signInAnonymously()
.then(() => {
  // Signed in..
})
.catch((error) => {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Then you can put your rules like:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

Then in authentication, you can activate the a anonymous method for sign in and add your authorized domains.

Comment: Have you tested this? I tried authenticating anonymously from a non-listed domain and I can still fetch data from Firestore...

Comment: I tested this and used it. Remember to add the rules in firestore rules and also add the domain you want to allow

Comment: Does signing in anonymously prevent you from doing so signin in with a specific account?

Comment: I think you can have both systems