# Is it possible to add rule to Firebase Realtime Database for checking app's package?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is it possible to write the rule which will allow reading data from FirebaseRD only for the app users (a rule which will check the app's package). I didn't find any information about it, all examples I found were with auth

Comment: *firebaser here* At the moment this is not possible. All you can check is the path of the data being accessed, the data being read or written, and the `auth` state of the user on the client. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018041/locking-down-firebase-db-access-to-specific-apps/52018178#52018178