# Firestore Security Rules - Accept requests from a verified Android App added in the GCP API Restrictions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an Android App, which uses Firebase RTDB & Firestore.

I added an Application restriction using the Android App Package Name (as shown in the attached image) but I figure I would still need to authenticate this key somewhere in Firebase Security Rules.
[image: GCP application restriction]

I want to make sure only my android app is able to access my firebase database.

How would my Firebase rule look like?

Thanks,

Comment: "make sure only my android app is able to access my firebase database" This is _currently_ not possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018041/locking-down-firebase-db-access-to-specific-apps. If there's news, I'll update there. :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks Frank! I'll keep an eye out for updates, your answer to the other question is very helpful!