# Restrict access to firebase realtime database to my app only

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to implement authentication in Xamarin Forms app towards firebase realtime database. So that there is restriction on accessing db only from my app and not allowing everyone to read and write to db?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check), which does precisely that.

It's no guarantee though as a sufficiently motivated user can still bypass such measures, so you'll also still want to [implement the necessary instructions in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started).

Also see:

- [Locking down Firebase DB access to specific apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018041/locking-down-firebase-db-access-to-specific-apps)
- And these other [questions about only granting access to the database from your app](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+realtime+database+my+app+only).