# Is there any realtime firebase database rules that permit only app sign in with a particular key to able to read and write?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app but I only want my app that is sign with my keystore to write or read from my database. I want to know if there is such realtime database rules for that

I am looking such rules, but I am finding it difficult

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to limit access to your Realtime Database to only apps that are signed by your custom keystore.

The closest is Firebase App Check, which works with on-device attestation providers to ensure database calls come from your application on a genuine device. But to apply your own keystore there, you'd have to [create your own App Check provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-provider).

Note that the topic of [restricting database access to just my app](https://www.google.com/search?q=restricting+firebase+realtime+database+access+to+just+my+app) has come up a few times before, so I also recommend checking out:

- [Locking down Firebase DB access to specific apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018041/locking-down-firebase-db-access-to-specific-apps) (and the posts linked from there)
- [Restrict Firebase database access to one Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818782/restrict-firebase-database-access-to-one-android-app)
- [What rules do I set in my firebase real-time database such that only specific users registered in my project can access it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74419640/what-rules-do-i-set-in-my-firebase-real-time-database-such-that-only-specific-us)
- [Restrict access to firebase realtime database to my app only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74995232/restrict-access-to-firebase-realtime-database-to-my-app-only)